# What is wrong with this statement (uniformly continuous function)

Tags: analysis

I have an assignment where I have to find a flaw in a proof, and I think I understand what I have to pinpoint at. I think there's something wrong with the interval $I$.

The statement is that the function $\sin : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

If we set the interval $I=[0,2\pi]$ we get that for all $\epsilon >0$ exists a $\delta'>0$ so that

$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|<\epsilon$ when $|x-y|<\delta'$ and $x,y\in I$

What is wrong with the above? The interval have to be bigger, and if so, why?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is about the function $\sin$ on $\mathbb R$.  So what is your justification for restricting $x$ and $y$ to an interval $I$, rather than allowing them to be any real numbers?